# Splitting long commands in shell scripts

Tags: shell-script

I have been writing Unix shell scripts, but I'm inexperienced in proper formatting. There were many instances where I had to write long lines to be executed as a single command.

Question is: Is there a way that I can split a single long line of a shell command into multiple lines, yet make it execute as a single command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either break apart the long string into smaller, and maybe more readable, components or use a trailing "\" to denote a break in the line.

from 'man bash':

> If a `\<newline>` pair appears,  and  the  backslash  is  not itself
> quoted,  the `\<newline>` is treated as a line continuation (that is, it
> is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).

Comment: Note that the backslash must be the **last** character on the line: be careful not to add any spaces after it.

Answer (score 13):

A long line in a single simple command may be split by escaping the newline like this:

```bsh
rsync --archive --itemize-changes \
    "$source" \
    "$target"
```

The backslash must be the last character on the line.

The relevant bit from the POSIX standard:

> 2.2.1 Escape Character (Backslash)
>
> A `<backslash>` that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a `<newline>`. If a `<newline>` follows the `<backslash>`, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The `<backslash>` and `<newline>` shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens. Since the escaped `<newline>` is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator.

In a single compound command, like a pipeline or and/or-list etc., there are often natural points for newlines that don't need to be escaped (as the `&&`, `||` and `|` are command terminators):

```bsh
[ -e "$pathname" ] &&
printf 'Removing %s\n' "$pathname" &&
rm -- "$pathname"
```

```bsh
awk -f script.awk <infile |
grep -e "$pattern" |
cat header.txt - >result.txt
```